# Does the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a^{nk}b^{mk}}{(nk)!(mk)!}$ have a closed-form solution?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am currently trying to find a closed form formula for this series:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a^{nk}b^{mk}}{(nk)!(mk)!}$$

with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^*_+$, $n,m \in \mathbb{N}^*$, $\gcd(n,m) = 1$. (Don't know if this info is relevant)

I tried to find first the closed form formula for the easier series:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a^{nk}}{(nk)!}$$

And intuitively by generalizing: $\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}$
I found: $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{\omega^k x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{nk}}{(nk)!}$, with $\omega = e^{2i\pi/n}$.

Wondering if with all of this information it is possible to find a closed form formula for the first series.

Comment: There's not going to be a closed form (depending on your definition of closed form.) There might be a way to write it in terms of known special functions. For $m=1$ and $n=1$ we get a [modified Bessel function of the first kind.](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html)

Comment: Yes, but it should be a “last resourt”; use the [FoxH](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoxH.html) function. Also, simplify by setting $(a^nb^m)^k=x^k$. If $m,n=2^c,c\in\Bbb N$, then use the [Legendre duplication formula](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=legendre+duplication+formula) multiple times and use the [hypergeometric function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=HypergeometricPFQ)

Comment: Another "renaming-style" formulation: $\frac1{2\pi i}\oint\exp(az^m+bz^{-n})\frac{dz}{z}$.

Answer (score 1):

As **@Tyma Gaidash** wrote in the comment
we can express with [FoxH](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoxH.html)  special function.

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^{nk} b^{mk}}{(nk)!(mk)!} = H_{1,3}^{1,1}\bigg(-a^n b^m\bigg|{(0,1) \atop (0,1),(0,m),(0,n)}\bigg) $$

Mathematica code:

`Inactivate[ Sum[(a^(n k)*b^(m k))/(((n k)!)*((m k)!)), {k, 0, Infinity}] ==  FoxH[{{{0, 1}}, {}}, {{{0, 1}}, {{0, m}, {0, n}}}, -a^n b^m], Sum]`

Comment: More simply, it is a [Fox-Wright function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox–Wright_function), but that function is not directly in Mathematica nor other softwares.

Comment: Try to avoid using images in answers if possible. We have people who are sight-impaired on this site, and images make it impossible for them to contribute meaningfully.

Comment: @TymaGaidash It's **FoxH** function **not** Fox-Wright function. **Mathematica**  has implemented this special function it was introduced in version **12.3.**

Comment: @CameronWilliams. Thanks you for editing. Mathematica can't convert **FoxH** function as TeXformat, probably a bug in **TeXForm** function.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Fox-wright is a special case of FoxH, as seen in the [photo](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/ffe83e472f89f4a998dc750566a980c28def03b3) and [article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox–Wright_function)